# Report from backend to upload to s3 using carrierwave gem ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have Axlsx::Package.new object which is used to create a excel file in backend and now i have to upload this excel file to s3 using carrierwave gem. I have either file path or Axlsx::Package.new object but in both case it is throwing file can't be blank.. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Please help me how can I achieve this.

> class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
>    # CarrierWave
>    mount_uploader :file, AttachmentUploader
>    validates :file, presence: true
>   end

when  I execute this line, where I don't have ActionDispath::FileUpload object as i am creating file in backend not from UI form. due to this I have

> file = Axlsx::Package.new
>   file_path = "uploads/exports/download_request_#{current_datetime}.xlsx"

```
 attachment = Attachment.create!(file: file, entity_type: self.class)
```

i tried with file also and file_path also but it is not working and throwing file can't be blank...

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  # CarrierWave
  mount_uploader :file, AttachmentUploader
  validates :file, presence: true
 end
```

it should save to s3 as how it is working in case when i upload file from UI form using input type file tag.

Please help